# React Router V5 | setup 404 page | status from API

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am building a React JS app with react-router v5.
I have already set up a 404 page and it works well.
As you can see, in the console I’m getting response code I just need to understand how to set a 404 header in the React component from this api response.
I looked up this question and everyone says you should set it from server response, but I did not figure it out, because I'm here now for your help.
Thank you

```
import React from "react";

const baseURL = "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/";
const phpRoute = "giveme404"; //if you put here "random" will work

class NotFoundPage extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(baseURL + phpRoute)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>404 Error, Page not found</div>;
  }
}

export default NotFoundPage;
```

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-lichterman-olrz8?file=/src/App.js)

Response From Server
[image: Response From Server]

Get response from server to React
[image: Get response from server to React]

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by *how to set a 404 header in the React component from this api response*? 404 is a status code and it's already set by the server together with the response headers, what's left for you is to handle that response somehow.

Comment: "what's left for you is to handle that response somehow." - this is where I failed... What means to handle? I'm already showing error page, getting 404 header from server and what else I should do? I really don't understand :(

Comment: Well, it depends on **when** you're trying to display this error page. With your code, you're always showing the error message, regardless of the response.

Comment: Yes because if I send user to this page I'm sure that there was an error... I just don't want error page as regular page, which just says it's error page. I want, like in PHP, you set error header and becomes real error page. Am I wrong? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: From what I understand you want to **redirect** to this page when certain condition happens (404 error)? For async requests like the one you've shown, you'll need to handle it in a more specific way in React, probably with Error boundary. It's not the same as writing https://www.google.com/non-existing if this is what you mean by *real error page*.

Comment: Yes you are totally right. Is "Error Boundary" correct way to do that? Or it's trick some kind of I should worry about? Also will google understand after boundary that this is error page?

Comment: Sorry to confuse you with the term 'error boundary'. Actually it's not applicable in this case, you can check my comment and links to find out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an [example error handling strategy](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-roentgen-zsbyi) you can adopt on the frontend.

Some highlights:

- I added some sample React routing with 404 page to which to redirect
  when certain conditions occur.
- I used the [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) library, because I'm not sure if the built-in `fetch`
  method in JS offers the same control as `axios` in terms of global
  error handling. Logic for api access logic is in **api.js** file, there
  you can see I added an error interceptor (more about interceptors [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors)) which kicks off whenever
  there's an unhandled http error and redirects to the not found page
  **only in case of 404 status code**.
- The trickies part is the history object. As you may know, React
  router keeps internally its own history object which handles route change subscriptions and you can't create
  your own one and expect React to detect changes from it. So you must
  access this object instead, it's harder to do it outside of a React
  component, though. All routed components like **MyFeatureComp** receive
  automatically the history object as prop. In its `componentDidMount` I
  store that value in a global variable so I have access to it in the
  api logic, but you'll need to come up with better approach I think, it's just for demo purposes.

Outside of this sample, [error boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) are nifty mechanism to handle errors **in your render functions (not event handlers)** (for either class or functional components). In my experience, I've used them mostly with the [render-as-you-fetch](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html#approach-3-render-as-you-fetch-using-suspense) strategy to incorporate them with the error boundaries. With that approach the request is effectively made in the render function as opposed to any callbacks like `componentDidMount`. But this is probably not the standard yet and official support will come probably in next major version, React 17.

I hope that helps, let me know if you have questions. ;)

Comment: As I understand, I have option to make it with Axios interceptors. If I return response with Axios interceptor, that's it? I handled error? After handling, should I see in browser developers tools that in headers status code is 404? Thank you so much for your time!!! :)

Comment: You don't *return response* with interceptor, but *modify the returned response from the server*. Unless you write something like ```throw error``` in the interceptor, the request is considered to be handled as success by the interceptor. I added also success callback to the interceptor (first parameter, previously was null). It just logs success message and returns the response from the callback. That return is very important in order to reach the handler in **MyFeatureComp**. You can see in the console that first the message from the interceptor is logged, then the response in MyFeatureComp.

Comment: ...when talking about the success path (using ```random``` value in the URL).

Comment: Regarding *should I see in browser developers tools that in headers status code is 404*, if **the server** returns 404 you will see it in the Network tab of Chrome's dev tools, regardless of what you do in the React code.

Comment: Hi Rosen, sorry for long time no answer. Thank you for detailed answer, it helped me to learn a lot from it. I was able to find interceptors for fetch "fetch-intercept", I also was able to modify fetch requests with this library and everything is working well. But one thing is not clear, after sending user to this page, will this also tell google (or other search engines) that this is 404 page?

Comment: If you mean SEO, that's a totally different topic than React and probably out of the scope of this question (I didn't see you mentioning SEO in the description). I'm not familiar with the details of SEO, but single page applications might require some extra effort to achieve good SEO as opposed to traditional websites. As I said in one of my previous comments, handling  async 404 responses is not the same *as writing google.com/non-existing*. For SEO you'll want to configure a generic 404 page at the server level, as Google says: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93641?hl=en

Comment: Also it's important to differentiate between routing at SPA level and at server level. If routing (or shall I say handling of the URL segments after the domain) happens entirely on the frontend and your server handles only the root route, that is www.yourdomain.com, a URL like www.yourdomain.com/not-existing **might** be considered a valid one and not return 404 depending on how you've configured your server.

Comment: Everything is clear now. This answer answers all the question what I asked. So I check this as "Accepted" :) Thank you so much for helping ;)

Comment: No problem! Glad I helped ;)